# Is there a way to update connector configuration using MSK-connect API?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, s3-kafka-connector, aws-msk-connect

I have an s3 connector deployed on MSK Connect, and a repository on github with the `json` connector configuration file. I'd like to update the connectors configuration on demand via MSK's REST API. I've checked the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/MSKC/latest/mskc/Welcome.html), but it seems like the `UpdateConnector` API only allows to modify the capacity configuration. The `CreateConnector` API does allow to provide connector configuration, but it returns an error if the connector already exists.
I could delete and then recreate the connector, but this doesn't seem like a good approach.

Is there another way to update a running connector configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on an answer I got from AWS, it's indeed not supported at the moment. It's in their roadmap, but they don't have an ETA at the moment.
They suggest to follow the information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/new/?whats-new-content-all.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-content-all.sort-order=desc&awsf.whats-new-analytics=*all&awsf.whats-new-app-integration=*all&awsf.whats-new-arvr=*all&awsf.whats-new-blockchain=*all&awsf.whats-new-business-applications=*all&awsf.whats-new-cloud-financial-management=*all&awsf.whats-new-compute=*all&awsf.whats-new-containers=*all&awsf.whats-new-customer-enablement=*all&awsf.whats-new-customer%20engagement=*all&awsf.whats-new-database=*all&awsf.whats-new-developer-tools=*all&awsf.whats-new-end-user-computing=*all&awsf.whats-new-mobile=*all&awsf.whats-new-gametech=*all&awsf.whats-new-iot=*all&awsf.whats-new-machine-learning=*all&awsf.whats-new-management-governance=*all&awsf.whats-new-media-services=*all&awsf.whats-new-migration-transfer=*all&awsf.whats-new-networking-content-delivery=*all&awsf.whats-new-quantum-tech=*all&awsf.whats-new-robotics=*all&awsf.whats-new-satellite=*all&awsf.whats-new-security-id-compliance=*all&awsf.whats-new-serverless=*all&awsf.whats-new-storage=*all), for upcoming improvements.

Answer (score 2):

If the Connect REST API is not directly accessible in other ways, then it seems that delete/recreate is the only option.

For sink connectors, that's a relatively safe option because consumer offsets are tracked by the connector name itself and there's no state stored outside of the internal Connect topics